# Mean stack :ReferenceError:

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I've created a schema called jobslist.js

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;


var jobListSchema = new Schema({
    companyName: String,
    jobtitle: String,
    location: String
});

var joblist = mongoose.model('jobList', jobListSchema);

module.exports = joblist;
```

this is my routes file user.js

```
    const jobList = require('../models/joblist');
        router.post('/appliedjobs', function(req,res) {
  console.log('posting applied jobs list');
  var appliedjob = new jobList();
      appliedjob.companyName = req.body.companyName;
      appliedjob.jobtitle =  req.body.jobtitle;
      appliedjob.location = req.body.location;
  console.log(appliedjob);
  appliedjob.save(function(err,joblist) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json({msg: 'job is saved'});
    }
  });
});

//get applied job list
router.get('/appliedjobs',function(req,res ) {
  console.log('getting applied jobs');
  appliedjob.find(function(err, appjobs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('unable to get jobs '+ err);
    } else {
      console.log('getting list');
      res.json(appjobs);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm getting error as

fetching jobs
getting applied jobs

> ReferenceError: appliedjob is not defined
>       at D:\product\project-1\routes\users.js:132:3
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
>       at Route.dispatch (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
>       at Function.process_params (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at D:\product\project-1\routes\users.js:15:3
>       at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
>       at trim_prefix (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
>       at D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
>       at Function.process_params (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
>       at next (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
>       at Function.handle (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:174:3)
>       at router (D:\product\project-1\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)

I have checked in my database(MongoDB), collection has been not generated.

Comment: You are also mixing ES2015 and ES5. Declare all var -> const or don't use const

Answer (score 1):

You should modify the last line of jobslist.js file.

Following is the proper exporting of mongoose model.

```
module.exports = { jobList : mongoose.model('jobList', jobListSchema) };
```

And while importing it change the first line

```
var JobList = require('../models/jobslist').jobList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below line when you create a model

```
var joblist = mongoose.model('jobList', jobListSchema, 'jobList');

module.exports = joblist;
```

Comment: Hey, Have you got error in fetching data from table or when you were inserting data into table?

Comment: both the times.

Answer (score 0):

`appliedjob` jobs is defined during `router.post` to `/appliedjobs`, in its callback and dies as soon as the function finishes, so it no longer exists in `router.get`

If you want it to persist, you need to declare `appliedjob` outside the function. Here is the new user.js file:

```
const jobList = require('../models/joblist');
let appliedjob; // now it's available to both functions below
//post joblist
router.post('/appliedjobs', function(req,res) {
  console.log('posting applied jobs list');
  appliedjob = new jobList({
     companyName : req.body.companyName,
     jobtitle :  req.body.jobtitle,
     location : req.body.location
  });
  console.log(appliedjob);
  appliedjob.save(function(err,joblist) {
    if(err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.json({msg: 'job is saved'});
    }
  });
});

//get applied job list
router.get('/appliedjobs',function(req,res ) {
  console.log('getting applied jobs');
  appliedjob.find(function(err, appjobs) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('unable to get jobs '+ err);
    } else {
      console.log('getting list');
      res.json(appjobs);
    }
  });
});
```

### **But!**

This way `appliedjob` will only be what you expect it to be **if** a `post` request happened **before** the `get` request.

I suggest you rethink the strategy a bit, so that if a `get` request happens first, you can recover.

Comment: ReferenceError: appliedjobs is not defined
This is the error i'm getting

Comment: appliedjob or appliedjobs?

Comment: ReferenceError: appliedjob is not defined.
I've copy-pasted your code.

Comment: And did you read the big bold **but**? Let me make it bigger. Done

Comment: yes I've tried to pass data through post man as {
 "companyName": "apple",
 "jobtitle": "systemadmin",
 "location": "torinto,canada"
}   but I'm getting error as TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;companyName&#39; of undefined

Comment: That's another issue. You should post a different question

Answer (score 0):

Declare variable appliedjob outside the function scope

Answer (score 0):

should use schema `jobList` instead of schema instance `appliedjob`.

```
//get applied job list
router.get('/appliedjobs',function(req,res ) {
  console.log('getting applied jobs');

    jobList.find(function(err, appjobs) {     //find by jobList schema
 // appliedjob.find(function(err, appjobs) { 

    if (err) {
      console.log('unable to get jobs '+ err);
    } else {
      console.log('getting list');
      res.json(appjobs);
    }
  });
});
```